# Why is function returning undefined when calling fetch, axios, ajax, or a promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, axios, fetch

When attempting to use asynchronous calls, the response is `undefined` rather than returning back the expected response data.

You can see how to run into this issue with any of the following examples:

#### Fetch

```js
const response = getDataWithFetch();
console.log(response);

function getDataWithFetch() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}
```

#### Axios

```js
const response = getDataWithAxios();
console.log(response);

function getDataWithAxios() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  axios.get(url).then(response => {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

#### AJAX / jQuery $.get

```js
const response = getDataWithAjax();
console.log(response);

function getDataWithAjax() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  $.get(url, (response) => {
    return response;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Promise

```js
const response = getDataWithPromise();
console.log(response);

function getDataWithPromise() {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const response = 'I am a response';
    return resolve(response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

Asynchronous calls, such as HTTP get requests via `fetch`, `axios`, `AJAX` or other asynchronous calls via `Promises` all behave similarly in that what is returned by the time that the function reaches its last line is not actually the result that you want.

### Explanation of Issue

This is because asynchronous calls do not wait for the call to finish executing before executing the next line:

> Note that in all the examples below, I will be using `fetch` but the concept could easily be extended to the other call types.

```js
getDataWithFetch();

function getDataWithFetch() {
  console.log('start of outer function');
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  fetch(url).then(response => {
     console.log('start of async function');
     response.json();
     console.log('end of async function');
  });
  console.log('end of outer function');
}
```

As you can see via **Run code snippet**, the `outer function` starts and ends before the `async function` starts.  What is `undefined` being returned from `getDataWithFetch()` because it is hitting the end of the function, and has no `return` statement.  If we change the code to add a return statement, we can see what part of the function call is actually being returned:

```js
const response = getDataWithFetch();
console.log(response);


function getDataWithFetch() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
  return 'hello world';
}
```

Now the function isn't returning `undefined` anymore, but it's not returning the `fetch` request response; instead, it is returning `'hello world'`.  This is because the `fetch` request is not blocking the rest of the `getDataWithFetch` function from executing.  To understand why, we need to understand what `fetch` is doing behind the scenes.

### Promises

#### Resolve

To do so, we need to understand Javascript Promises.  There's a great beginner-friendly read on it here: https://javascript.info/promise-basics, but in a nutshell:

> A Promise is an object that, when it finishes the asynchronous work, it will call the "resolve" function.  Where "resolve" returns the expected data via `resolve(dataToReturn)`.

So behind the scenes, `fetch` returns a `Promise` that will call `resolve` when the fetched data is retrieved, like so:

```js
// just an example of what fetch somewhat looks like behind the scenes
function fetch(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // waiting for response to come back from server
    // maybe doing a bit of additional work
    resolve(responseDataFromServer);
  });
}
```

With that understanding, we now know that we need to return the call to `fetch` to actually return the `Promise`, like so:

```js
const response = getDataWithFetch();
console.log(response);

function getDataWithFetch() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}
```

The `console.log` is no longer returning `undefined`, but it's not returning the right response either.  That's because `getDataWithFetch` is now returning the `Promise` object from `fetch`.  It's time to get the response from `resolve`.

### .then

To get the data passed to the `resolve` function, we need to use the `then` method on the returned `Promise`.

> A `Promise` provides the method `then` to retrieve the value passed to `resolve` as such: `myReturnedPromise.then(dataToReturn => { /* do something with the data */ });`.  `then` will only execute once the `dataToReturn` is ready to be handled.

### Final Solution

So by using the `then` method, we can get the actual response printed to console:

```js
getDataWithFetch().then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});

function getDataWithFetch() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}
```

And there you have it!

#### Overly Verbose Solution

If there was too much magic in what made that solution work, you can also see the breakdown of it by explicitly returning a `Promise` to be fulfilled:

```js
getDataWithFetch().then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});

function getDataWithFetch() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
    return fetch(url).then(response => {
      resolve(response.json()));
      // Note that the `resolve` does not have to be part of the `return`
    }
  });
}
```

#### Async and Await Solution

Recent improvements to Javascript have provided us with a more succinct way of handling `Promises` to make them **appear** synchronous instead of asynchronous.  Note that the following code is equivalent to the above solutions, but much easier to read:

```js
async function getDataWithFetch() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
}

getDataWithFetch().then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

`async` and `await` are clean and powerful alternatives to explicitly dealing with `Promises`, especially when [Promise Chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) is involved.  I recommend reading more about them here: https://javascript.info/async-await.

Comment: Overly Verbose Solution Fixed it in my case. Thank you so much for explaining this!